# Python doesnt add a string to a string and i dont get an error, even if i use it correctly

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

So basically I am making an encrypter that uses the Vigenère square, but for some reason Python only stores the first letter of the message successfully and then while it does the commands and encrypts each character it doesn't add them in the message variable:

```
message=str()
keyword="ΒΑΡΕΘΗΚΑ"
string="ΑΝΚΑΤΑΦΕΡΕΣΝΑ"

charNum=[913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937]
charTable={ "Α" : 0, "Β" : 1, "Γ" : 2, "Δ" : 3, "Ε" : 4, "Ζ" : 5, "Η" : 6, "Θ" : 7, "Ι" : 8, "Κ" : 9, "Λ" : 10, "Μ" : 11, "Ν" : 12, "Ξ" : 13, "Ο" : 14, "Π" : 15, "Ρ" : 16, "Σ" : 17, "Τ" : 18, "Υ" : 19, "Φ" : 20, "Χ" : 21, "Ψ" : 22, "Ω" : 23}


i=0
for char in string:
    character=charTable[char] + charTable[keyword[i]]
    if character > 23:
        character -= 24
    message += chr(charNum[character])
    print(message)

    i+=1
    if i==len(keyword):
        i=0
```

Outputs:

```
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
Β
```

Which is supposed to show the message every time it adds a letter.

If i change the

```
print(message)
```

to

```
print(chr(charNum[character]))
```

The output is this:

```
Β
Ν
Β
Ε
Β
Η
Ζ
Ε
Σ
Ε
Κ
Ρ
Θ
```

Which is each correctly encrypted letter.
What is happening?

Comment: Me too, which looks what you intended right?

Comment: I get `Β`, `ΒΝ`, `ΒΝΒ`...`ΒΝΒΕΒΗΖΕΣΕΚΡΘ` when I run your code.

Comment: @toonarmycaptain what version are you using

Comment: @progmatico which python version?

Comment: tested with v3.6.2, v3.5 and v3.2

Comment: Tried in 3.6.1 and 3.6.3. It didn't run in 2.7.10 due to non-ASCII keys or something.

Comment: i just tested with 3.6 and worked but 3.4 doesnt gues i am installing 3.6 xD @progmatico

Comment: @progmatico i dont know whats wrong to be exact. but for some reason 3.6.3 works so i guess i dont need a fix

Comment: thx to @progmatico

Comment: and @toonarmycaptain for their time

Comment: Not sure that version is your issue, since I get the same [result running on Python 3.4](https://www.ideone.com/tOtjOh)

Answer (score 0):

Take the print(message) out of the for loop and put it at the end:

```
message=str()
keyword="ΒΑΡΕΘΗΚΑ"
string="ΑΝΚΑΤΑΦΕΡΕΣΝΑ"

charNum=[913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924, 925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937]
charTable={ "Α" : 0, "Β" : 1, "Γ" : 2, "Δ" : 3, "Ε" : 4, "Ζ" : 5, "Η" : 6, "Θ" : 7, "Ι" : 8, "Κ" : 9, "Λ" : 10, "Μ" : 11, "Ν" : 12, "Ξ" : 13, "Ο" : 14, "Π" : 15, "Ρ" : 16, "Σ" : 17, "Τ" : 18, "Υ" : 19, "Φ" : 20, "Χ" : 21, "Ψ" : 22, "Ω" : 23}

i=0
for char in string:
    character=charTable[char] + charTable[keyword[i]]
    if character > 23:
        character -= 24
    message += chr(charNum[character])
    i+=1
    if i==len(keyword):
        i=0
print(message)
```